# Disable nlog logging in PostSharp 5.x

Tags: nlog, postsharp

Logging in NLog can be disabled with `LogManager.DisableLogging();`

With PostSharp+NLog combination how do I do it?

Comment: Why not calling `LogManager.DisableLogging()`?

Answer (score 1):

Enabling and disabling PostSharp logging is described in detail at http://doc.postsharp.net/log-enabling.

In short, you have two options:

1) Disable logging via the PostSharp API for a specific logging role and namespace, for example

`LoggingServices.DefaultBackend.GetSource(LoggingRoles.Tracing, MyCompany.BusinessLayer").SetLevel(LogLevel.Debug);`

2) Use the logging back-end API.

You may need to do some set-up before using this approach as described in the doc.

However, the `LogManager.DisableLogging();` of NLog is recognized by PostSharp out of the box, so you can use this one to disable the logging completely including PostSharp logging.

Comment: In the below code, LogManager.DisableLogging() made no impact and I still get the method entry/exit traces.        
  `static void Main(string[] args)
    {
            LoggingServices.DefaultBackend = new PostSharp.Patterns.Diagnostics.Backends.Console.ConsoleLoggingBackend();
            NLog.LogManager.DisableLogging();
            f();
          
        }
        [Log]
        public static void  f()
        {
        
        }
    }`

Comment: That's because you are using the `ConsoleLoggingBackend` instead of the `NLogLoggingBackend`. To make the PostSharp Logging use NLog, add packages *PostSharp.Patterns.Diagnostics* and *PostSharp.Patterns.Diagnostics.NLog* to your project, initialize NLog according to NLog documentation and set PostSharp to use NLog by `LoggingServices.DefaultBackend = new PostSharp.Patterns.Diagnostics.Backends.Console.NLogLoggingBackend(); `.